# rewrite url is not working in core php localhost project

Tags: php, url-rewriting, user-friendly

I have to to make my URL into a friendly URL.

I have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule http://localhost/test/client/this_is_test_page.php$ http://localhost/test/test-page [NC,R=301,L]
```

but now I'm getting HTTP 500 internal server error.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have HTTP_HOST in your pattern according to the apache documentation :

> A RewriteRule consists of three arguments separated by spaces. The
>   arguments are :
>
> 1. Pattern: which incoming URLs should be affected by the rule;
> 2. Substitution: where should the matching requests be sent;
> 3. [flags]: options affecting the rewritten request.
>
> The Pattern is a regular expression. It is initially (for the first
>   rewrite rule or until a substitution occurs) matched against the
>   URL-path of the incoming request (**the part after the hostname** but
>   before any question mark indicating the beginning of a query string)

Your rule should be something like :

```
RewriteRule /test/client/this_is_test_page.php$ /test/test-page [NC,R=301,L]
```

And you should have `mod_rewrite` enabled, `RewriteEngine On` and `AllowOverride`.

Comment: A wrong .htaccess file results to a server error (500), you should post your entire .htaccess to get an answer to your question.

Comment: how can i skip the test before test-page ?

Comment: RewriteBase /test (i guess this is your entire site, check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase )

Comment: I have my all pages in test directory, but i want to access them without test directory in the url, except the admin url.

how can i do that ?

Comment: Oulalahakabu

can you help me?